# how to launch a cmd exe at current working directory with shortcut?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

My OS is Win7. When I need to open a cmd.exe at current working directory, I will press "shift" key and right click the screen and I will get "Open command window here". Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's the fastest way... Doing it with a keyboard would be longer than doing it with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You could script it. This [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) script opens a command window on the folder you're currently browsing by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; for use in explorer.
^!h::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send !d
Sleep 10
Send ^c
Run, cmd /K "cd `"%clipboard%`""
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved =
return
#IfWinActive
```

Courtesy of Lifehacker reader [Kevin](http://lifehacker.com/5306401/open-a-new-command-prompt-from-explorer-with-a-hotkey).

Answer (score 0):

Try `alt + d`, type `cmd`, then press Enter.

Comment: @CanadianLuke You sure? It works for me. Alt+D takes you to the address bar, where you type in "cmd" and press enter to open up the prompt. Try just typing "cmd" in the address bar

Comment: The issue was I was in a "Library" set of folders. Any other folder, and it works. My bad

Comment: It's fine, I learned something new thanks to you. I didn't know a Library folder would do that